# Using strings and variables in println statements

Tags: java

I am writing a program that finds a user's ideal weight by asking for their height in inches and feet. So far everything looks alright except the final statement, in which I return to the user the average weight for a male and female, and also tell them the range of their weight between 15%. Here is the code that gives me a problem:

```
System.out.println("For a male, the height " + foot "' " +
                   inches + "/""" + " and it's ideal weight is " + 
                   mWeight + "lbs. Anything between " + minMaleLb +
                   "lbs and " + maxMaleLb + "lbs is okay.");
System.out.println("For a female, the height " + foot "' " +
                   inches + "/""" + " and it's ideal weight is " + 
                   fWeight + "lbs. Anything between " + minFeMaleLb +
                   "lbs and " + maxFeMaleLb + "lbs is okay.");
```

And here are the errors I receive while compiling:

```
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 26]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:26: ')' expected
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 27]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:27: not a statement
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 27]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:27: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 29]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:29: not a statement
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 29]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:29: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 31]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:31: ')' expected
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 32]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:32: not a statement
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 32]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:32: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 34]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:34: not a statement
File: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java  [line: 34]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\IdealWeight.java:34: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\###\Java\Weight.java  [line: 30]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\Weight.java:30: reached end of file while parsing
File: C:\Users\###\Java\Weight.java  [line: 34]
Error: C:\Users\###\Java\Weight.java:34: reached end of file while parsing
```

Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with the code, and how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You're also missing a few +. Example : `foot "' "` instead of `foot + "' "`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that you're escaping your quotes wrong; that should be

```
... + "\"" + ...
```

for the quotemark.

EDIT: And as JB Nizet pointed out in a comment, you're missing the `+` after `foot`.

Also, you can simplify that expression a bit more with

```
... + "\" and the ideal weight is " + ...
```

rather than concatenating two separate strings.

Answer (score 17):

With all those concatenations, I'd sugest using [`System.out.format(format, args);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
System.out.format("For a male, the height %d' %d\" and its ideal weight is %dlbs. Anything between %dlbs and %dlbs is okay.",
    foot, inches, mWeight, minMaleLb, maxMaleLb);
```

You also have a spelling error:

```
and it's ideal weight is
```

should be

```
and its ideal weight is
```

"its" has no apostrophe (ie not "it's") when used in the possessive form

Comment: The grammar is completely off, and you're complaining about an apostrophe?

Answer (score 1):

The `"/"""` bits look wrong and could throw the parser off. Maybe you meant to use `"\""` (or even simpler, `'"'`)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that in java you could use strings in a format like System.out.println('"'); but it seems to only work with quotation marks. I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: @mooles: Single quotes delimit (single) characters, not strings. But printing methods and StringBuilder methods have overloads that accept characters. Also, the + operator on Strings automatically converts non-String operands to Strings; so, for example, `String s = "" + 123;` works.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "use strings in a format". This answer does not use anything that would normally be called "string formatting", and `System.out.println` is a method, not "a format".